# Intent dialog not searching bluetooth module

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth

**I am making an android app in which we communicate with arduino but the problem is that when i send character to bluetooth module it show an intent dialog choose option when i select bluetooth its search only mobile devices not bluetooth module???**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"b");
    intent.setType("text/plain");

    startActivity(intent);
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> appslist=pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);

    if(appslist.size()>0){
        String packagename=null;
        String classname=null;
        boolean found=false;

        for(ResolveInfo info:appslist){
            packagename=info.activityInfo.packageName;
            if(packagename.equals("com.example.app")){
                classname=info.activityInfo.name;
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!found){
            showToast("Bluetooth havn't been found");
        }else{
            intent.setClassName(packagename,classname);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need create a RFCOMM connection and write to outstream instead of using intent.

for more details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html